# How to plot a vector field?

Tags: computational-physics, vector-fields, software

I am reading articles of vector fields, such as magnetic field and sound field. I am very curious about how the vector fields are drawn, such as the pictures shown below.

Any reference to this question would be greatly appreciated, especially those that using Matlab to plot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are predefined matlab functions to draw plots such as these, the first one is something called "contour" and the second is called "quiver". [Check this link out](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html)

Comment: @ecook No problem, please mark the reply as the answer